Frequent D State and zombies processes (Acronis, MySQL, Java, Journal D) - Possibly Related to KVM Asynchronous Page Faults
I've observed that several processes, including Acronis, MySQL, Java applications, and Journal D, are frequently entering the D state. This state seems to be related to paging, specifically to KVM asynchronous page faults.
Here’s the relevant thread stack trace:
Thread Stack:
[<0>] kvm_async_pf_task_wait_schedule+0x15c/0x1a0
[<0>] __kvm_handle_async_pf+0x4c/0x90
[<0>] do_page_fault+0x7b/0x12d
[<0>] page_fault+0x1e/0x30

Process wait channel
0 
rchar: 708830538
wchar: 209770024
syscr: 1053758
syscw: 29808
read_bytes: 112185856
write_bytes: 1970216960
cancelled_write_bytes: 73773056

Here's the dmesg log
Frozen Java process

[  +0.000162] Call Trace:
[  +0.000144]  __schedule+0x2d1/0x870
[  +0.000156]  ? wait_consider_task+0xf0/0x940
[  +0.000154]  schedule+0x55/0xf0
[  +0.000160]  do_wait+0x165/0x2f0
[  +0.000326]  kernel_wait4+0xa6/0x140
[  +0.000360]  ? task_stopped_code+0x50/0x50
[  +0.000143]  __do_sys_wait4+0x87/0xa0
[  +0.000157]  ? handle_mm_fault+0xca/0x2a0
[  +0.000141]  ? syscall_trace_enter+0x1ff/0x2d0
[  +0.000141]  ? __do_page_fault+0x1e9/0x420
[  +0.000139]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x1b0
[  +0.000135]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xc6
[  +0.000150] RIP: 0033:0x7fdbebffa68b
[  +0.000138] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7fdbebffa661.
[  +0.000159] RSP: 002b:00007ffe8baa3ab8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000003d
[  +0.000150] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000000000000000a RCX: 00007fdbebffa68b
[  +0.000149] RDX: 000000000000000a RSI: 00007ffe8baa3ae0 RDI: 00000000ffffffff
[  +0.000152] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 000055cc375727c0 R09: 0000000000000001
[  +0.000150] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000001
[  +0.000160] R13: 00007ffe8baa3bb0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00007ffe8baa3ae0
[  +0.000156] task:java            state:S stack:0     pid:1164  ppid:1      flags:0x00000080

Frozen process' thread is in D state (Thread id: 1393)
[  +0.000197] Call Trace:
[  +0.000160]  ? __raw_spin_unlock_irq+0x5/0x20
[  +0.000165]  ? __schedule+0x6fa/0x870
[  +0.000161]  ? syscall_slow_exit_work+0x109/0x130
[  +0.000165]  ? do_syscall_64+0x174/0x1b0
[  +0.000171]  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xc6
[  +0.000182] task:java            state:D stack:0     pid:1393  ppid:1      flags:0x00000080
...
[  +0.000822] Showing busy workqueues and worker pools:
[  +0.000271] workqueue events: flags=0x0
[  +0.000269]   pwq 12: cpus=6 node=0 flags=0x0 nice=0 active=1/256 refcnt=2
[  +0.000257]     pending: drm_fb_helper_damage_work [drm_kms_helper]
[  +0.000290] workqueue events_power_efficient: flags=0x80
[  +0.000280]   pwq 12: cpus=6 node=0 flags=0x0 nice=0 active=1/256 refcnt=2
[  +0.000269]     pending: fb_flashcursor
[  +0.000275] workqueue mm_percpu_wq: flags=0x8
[  +0.000249]   pwq 12: cpus=6 node=0 flags=0x0 nice=0 active=1/256 refcnt=2
[  +0.000268]     pending: vmstat_update
[  +0.017227] sysrq: SysRq : Show Blocked State
[  +0.000744] task:java            state:D stack:0     pid:1393  ppid:1      flags:0x00000080
[  +0.000400] Call Trace:
[  +0.000243]  __schedule+0x2d1/0x870
[  +0.000249]  schedule+0x55/0xf0
[  +0.000246]  kvm_async_pf_task_wait_schedule+0x15c/0x1a0
[  +0.000235]  __kvm_handle_async_pf+0x4c/0x90
[  +0.000224]  do_page_fault+0x7b/0x12d
[  +0.000229]  ? page_fault+0x8/0x30
[  +0.000239]  page_fault+0x1e/0x30
[  +0.000238] RIP: 0033:0x7f64475fa14f
[  +0.000226] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f64475fa125.
[  +0.000230] RSP: 002b:00007f644465abb8 EFLAGS: 00010202
[  +0.000233] RAX: 0000000710387240 RBX: 0000000710387240 RCX: 0000000711c6b180
[  +0.000257] RDX: 00000000006ba180 RSI: 00000007af520678 RDI: 00000007115b0fd0
[  +0.000215] RBP: 00007f644465ac30 R08: fffffffffffffff0 R09: 00007f644758abf8
[  +0.000213] R10: 0000000711c6b190 R11: 0000000710387240 R12: 00000007ae2f68a8
[  +0.000221] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 000000000031c7ea

Free memory
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.7Gi       5.8Gi       4.0Gi       6.8Gi       8.3Gi
Swap:         7.5Gi       623Mi       6.8Gi

The virtual guests are allocated fixed amounts of memory, and there is more than enough memory available in each guest (no over-commits). The disk caching is currently set to writeback, but I am considering switching it to writethrough as a safer option, though I’m unsure if this would address the issue.
Has anyone encountered similar issues, or can you suggest potential causes for these paging-related faults?

Where is this stack trace from? The VM (qemu/kvm instance on the host system) or the individual application? When in this state what is the output of /proc/pressure/memory and /proc/pressure/io on the VM?

The is no /proc/pressure. I've updated my post to include both the partial stack information of the thread and kernel logs.

Do you have kernel same page merging enabled? The D state being a page fault is oddly suspicious..

Yes, KSM is enabled on the server. I am considering turning off KSM on one of the problem server. I noticed that D state clears if I pause the VM and resume the VM.
Frequency of problems differs, sometimes the D state runs for several months without issues and other it's in a few days.
